# Reboot MTK device in metamode

Tags: android, adb

I have a lenovo s860 with broken power button currently in meta mode. Is there any way to halt it or better reboot it trough shell? As adb doesn't react with offline devices.

Also I cannot remove the devices battery.

(currently using ubuntu)

Any suggestions would be wonderful!

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Maui Meta tool and then connect the device to your PC. Once the meta tool has done a handshake with your device then use adb shell to reboot.